# Vertical scrolling issue

Tags: css, html, scroll

http://louisehall.clanteam.com/ is the website in question.

I designed this homepage to be horizontal scrolling only, which works on certain size monitors. However obviously on small browser windows the vertical scroll bar appears meaning the layout is ruined when the user scrolls down i.e. the 'Louise Hall' image and the navigation bar appear over the images.

I have done some research, however the answers I have found haven't really helped. It may be my amateur CSS knowledge but you catch my drift.

If you look at this website for example: http://www.banksy.co.uk/outdoors/outusa/horizontal_1.htm

The navigation area is fixed no matter what size the browser window.

Is there anyway I can fix the 'Louise Hall' and navigation bar horizontally (as it is now) but then make it scroll vertically.

Thanks

Josh

Answer (score 1):

That *fixed* is achieved using `position: fixed`.

However, in the example you linked to, they are using frames. I wouldn't recommend using frames.

Comment: Both items are positioned to be fixed and is why they do not move when you scroll horizontally. I want them to be essentially fixed horizontally but not vertically